# How do I update a RoundRectDataList (in Dojo +1.7)?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I was trying a example from this link http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/mobile/RoundRectDataList that I put here:

```
require([
    "dojo/ready",
    "dojo/data/ItemReadStore",
    "dojox/mobile/RoundRectDataList",
    "dojox/mobile",
    "dojox/mobile/parser"
], function(ready, ItemFileReadStore, RoundRectDataList){
    ready(function(){
        var storeData = {
            "items": [
                { "label": "Wi-Fi", "icon": "images/i-icon-3.png", "rightText": "Off",  "moveTo": "bar" },
                { "label": "VPN", "icon": "images/i-icon-4.png", "rightText": "VPN",  "moveTo": "bar" }
            ]
        };
        var sampleStore = new ItemFileReadStore({data:storeData});
        var dataList = new RoundRectDataList({store:sampleStore}, "dataList");
        dataList.startup();
    });
});
```

and the html part:

```
<ul id="dataList"></ul>
```

The problem is that I can't put this on a button and repeat the same code. Because a get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Tried to register widget with id==dataList but that id is already registered
```

If I destroy or empty the node it doesnt appear anymore.... What should I do? Destroy and create the same `<ul>` on DOM?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Hope we'll be able to help you.

Comment: I discovered how to do what I wanted but I was not able to answer my own question. Sorry for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for this. But I just found a way to do what I was trying:

```
  require([
    "dojo/on",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dojox/mobile/parser",    // This mobile app uses declarative programming with fast mobile parser
    "dojox/mobile",           // This is a mobile app.
    "dijit/dijit",
    "dijit/registry",         
    "dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore",
    "dojox/mobile/RoundRectDataList",
    "dojo/_base/array",
    "dojo/domReady!"
  ], function(on, dom, domConstruct, parse, mobile, dijit, registry, itemFileReadStore, roundRectDataList) {
    self = this;

    populateVistoriasList = function() {
      var idx = 'vistoriasList'
      var vistoriasList = dijit.byId( idx );
      if ( vistoriasList && vistoriasList instanceof roundRectDataList )
        vistoriasList.destroyRecursive(false);

      domConstruct.destroy( idx );
      domConstruct.create('ul', {id: idx }, 'vistoriasListContainer');

      self.storeData = {
          "items": [
              { "label": "Wi-Fi", "icon": "images/i-icon-3.png", "rightText": "Off", "moveTo": "bar" },
              { "label": "VPN", "icon": "images/i-icon-4.png", "rightText": "VPN", "moveTo": "bar" }
          ]
      };
      self.sampleStore = new itemFileReadStore({data:storeData});
      self.dataList = new roundRectDataList({store:sampleStore}, idx );
      self.dataList.startup();
    }
```

It worked very well... ;)
One more time, sorry for asking and answering the same question...

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way to do reload the ItemFileReadStore into the [RoundRectDataList](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/mobile/RoundRectList.html#dojox-mobile-roundrectlist), using the RoundRectDataList.refresh function.

```
 require([
"dojo/on",
"dojo/dom",
"dojo/dom-construct",
"dojox/mobile/parser",    // This mobile app uses declarative programming with fast mobile parser
"dojox/mobile",           // This is a mobile app.
"dijit/dijit",
"dijit/registry",         
"dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore",
"dojox/mobile/RoundRectDataList",
"dojo/_base/array",
"dojo/domReady!"
], function(on, dom, domConstruct, parse, mobile, dijit, registry, itemFileReadStore, roundRectDataList) {
var self = this;

populateVistoriasList = function() {
  var idx = 'vistoriasList',
      vistoriasList = dijit.byId( idx );

  self.storeData = {
      "items": [
          { "label": "Wi-Fi", "icon": "images/i-icon-3.png", "rightText": "Off", "moveTo": "bar" },
          { "label": "VPN", "icon": "images/i-icon-4.png", "rightText": "VPN", "moveTo": "bar" }
      ]
  };
  self.sampleStore = new itemFileReadStore({data:storeData});

  if ( vistoriasList && vistoriasList instanceof roundRectDataList ) {
    vistoriasList.store = self.sampleStore;
    vistoriasList.refresh(); 
  } else {
    self.dataList = new roundRectDataList({store:self.sampleStore}, idx );
    self.dataList.startup();
  }
}
```